# (React and Firebase deploy) blank page when refreshing

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-hosting

I started learning react and firebase to make a simple app with react-router-dom, everything works fine in localhost but when I deploy to firebase the routing only works if im navigating with the links, if I refresh the page or manually change the url it returns a white page, the console logs:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
main.13106e0c.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
```

Another thing to say is that it only happens with routes that has parameters, for example   `path="/categories/:name"` the other ones like `path="/login/"` works fine.

I've seen that there are some posts about a similar error, but no one worked for me yet

Comment: It most likely works locally because you have [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) enabled. You need to make sure that your server serves the `index.html` file for all of your routes in production.

Comment: If what @Tholle says is the cause, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites

Comment: firebase asks you if you want to redirect all urls to /index.html so it seems not to be the problem

Comment: Then it might be that your JS files don't have a `/` in front of their names in the script tag `src` attribute inside `index.html`, which will make it so the JS files are loaded relative to the current URL, e.g. `/login/main.13106e0c.chunk.js` instead of just `main.13106e0c.chunk.js` like you want it to.

Comment: You are right! it was the `/` I wouldn´t imagine